# how wait some time without Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I have used GCP java SDK for start/stop instance. My current problem is I want to wait some time after start or stop until change instance status to `RUNNING` or `STOPPED`. I want to do this without using `Thread.sleep()`.

this is my current code:-

```
private void waitDone(Operation operation) throws IOException, 
       InterruptedException {
    String status = operation.getStatus();

    while (!status.equals("DONE")) {
        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        Compute.ZoneOperations.Get get = 
        getCompute().zoneOperations().get(projectId, zone,
                operation.getName());
        operation = get.execute();

        if (operation != null) {
            status = operation.getStatus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove it? in the loop check if the status is `RUNNING` or `STOPPED`.

Comment: For solving indefinite wait problem, you can use a retry counter, and exit the loop either if the status changes to done OR you hit the max retry count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay. Something like this

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
  Compute.ZoneOperations.Get get = 
  getCompute().zoneOperations().get(projectId, zone, operation.getName());
  operation = get.execute();

  if (operation != null && operation.getStatus().equals("DONE")) {
     executor.shutdown();
  }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//if you need to block current thread
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to block your program while waiting for the status to change (which makes sense), put the waiting in a separate thread.

How to create a thread and start it is explained in many places, so I don’t see any point in repeating the code here. Just search.

As Manish said in a comment, for solving indefinite wait problem, you can use a retry counter and exit the loop either if the status changes to done *or* you hit the max retry count.

As an aside I consider this version of the wait slightly easier to read:

```
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

It works the same as `Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);`.